# Check if two scipy.sparse.csr_matrix are equal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to check if two [csr_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) are equal.

If I do:

```
x.__eq__(y)
```

I get:

```
raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

This, However, works well:

```
assert (z in x for z in y)
```

Is there a better way to do it? maybe using some `scipy` optimized function instead?

Thanks so much

Comment: Have you tried `(x==y).all()`? Just a guess...

Comment: `==` and `all` are not practical calculations for sparse matrices.  Most elements are 0.  `x==x` would produces a matrix of all `True`, which is no longer sparse.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Can we assume they are the same shape?

```
In [202]: a=sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1],[1,0]])
In [203]: b=sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1],[1,1]])
In [204]: (a!=b).nnz==0   
Out[204]: False
```

This checks the sparsity of the inequality array.

It will give you an efficiency warning if you try `a==b` (at least the 1st time you use it).  That's because it has to test all those zeros.  It can't take much advantage of the sparsity.

You need a relatively recent version to use logical operators like this.  Were you trying to use `x.__eq__(y)` in some `if` expression, or did you get error from just that expression?

In general you probably want to check several parameters first.  Same `shape`, same `nnz`, same `dtype`.  You need to be careful with floats.

For dense arrays `np.allclose` is a good way of testing equality.  And if the sparse arrays aren't too large, that might be good as well

```
np.allclose(a.A, b.A)
```

`allclose` uses  `all(less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y)))`.  You can use `a-b`, but I suspect that this too will give an efficiecy warning.

Comment: The best tips I could get, Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why `numpy.array_equal` doesn't appear to work as expected for two sparse inputs?

Comment: A scipy sparse matrix is not an `np.ndarray`.  It's an entirely different object class that stores its data in arrays.  Try `np.asarray(M)` for a small sample matrix.  Look at the result.  Also look at the code for `np.array_equal` (its Python).  In general `numpy` functions don't work on sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

## SciPy and Numpy Hybrid Method

What worked best for my case was (using a generic code example):

```
bool_answer = np.arrays_equal(sparse_matrix_1.todense(), sparse_matrix_2.todense())
```

You might need to pay attention to the equal_nan parameter in `np.arrays_equal`

The following doc references helped me get there:
[CSR Sparse Matrix Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)
[CSC Sparse Matrix Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix)
[Numpy arrays_equal method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)
[SciPy todense method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.todense.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.todense)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following checks for a fast comparison. It requires that both matrices have sorted indices though (via `.sort_indices()`):

```py
(len(x.indices) == len(y.indices)
    and np.all((x.indices - y.indices) == 0)
    and np.allclose((x.data - y.data), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Amir Ebrahimi's answer, a CSR matrix is typically characterised by two sets of indices, the attributes of the scipy instances are called `indices` and `indptr`. You probably want to check that these are identical between your two matrices, on top of checking that the matrices hold the same values. Something along the lines of

```
assert (
    np.all(x.indices == y.indices)
    and np.all(x.indptr == y.indptr)
    and np.allclose(x.data, y.data)
)
```

where all the arrays tested are 1D, no conversion to dense matrices necessary.

The indices array are integers, so an equality test is OK. If your `data` arrays are floats, using `allclose` will avoid rounding error problems, as suggested by @hpaulj. If you know your `data` are integers, you can use an equality test there as well.