# Why does np.array_equal return False for these two sparse arrays that are visually equal?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have two methods for calculating the unit vector of an array, both of which handle sparse arrays. One of them is very much a 'manual' computation, whereas the other is more 'formal' (from the gensim.matutils source code).

This is the manual method:

```
def manual_unitvec(vec):
        vec = vec.tocsr()
        if sparse.issparse(vec):
            vec_sum_of_squares = vec.multiply(vec)
            unit = 1. / np.sqrt(vec_sum_of_squares.sum())
            return vec.multiply(unit)
        elif not sparse.issparse(vec):
            sum_vec_squared = np.sum(vec ** 2)
            vec /= np.sqrt(sum_vec_squared)
            return vec
```

This is the modified gensim method, where the method explicitly computing the unit vector is `unitvec`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from gensim.matutils import ret_normalized_vec, blas
import scipy.sparse

blas_nrm2 = blas('nrm2', np.array([], dtype=float))
blas_scal = blas('scal', np.array([], dtype=float))


def unitvec(vec, norm='l2'):
    """Scale a vector to unit length.
    Parameters
    ----------
    vec : {numpy.ndarray, scipy.sparse, list of (int, float)}
        Input vector in any format
    norm : {'l1', 'l2'}, optional
        Normalization that will be used.
    Returns
    -------
    {numpy.ndarray, scipy.sparse, list of (int, float)}
        Normalized vector in same format as `vec`.
    Notes
    -----
    Zero-vector will be unchanged.
    """
    if norm not in ('l1', 'l2'):
        raise ValueError("'%s' is not a supported norm. Currently supported norms are 'l1' and 'l2'." % norm)

    if scipy.sparse.issparse(vec):
        print("INSIDE SPARSE HANDLING")
        vec = vec.tocsr()
        if norm == 'l1':
            veclen = np.sum(np.abs(vec.data))
        if norm == 'l2':
            veclen = np.sqrt(np.sum(vec.data ** 2))
        if veclen > 0.0:
            if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int) == True:
                vec = vec.astype(np.float)
                return vec / veclen
            else:
                vec /= veclen
                return vec.astype(vec.dtype)
        else:
            return vec

    if isinstance(vec, np.ndarray):
        print("INSIDE NORMAL VEC HANDLING")
        vec = np.asarray(vec, dtype=vec.dtype)
        if norm == 'l1':
            veclen = np.sum(np.abs(vec))
        if norm == 'l2':
            veclen = blas_nrm2(vec)
        if veclen > 0.0:
            if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int) == True:
                vec = vec.astype(np.float)
                return blas_scal(1.0 / veclen, vec).astype(vec.dtype)
            else:
                return blas_scal(1.0 / veclen, vec).astype(vec.dtype)
        else:
            return vec

    try:
        first = next(iter(vec))  # is there at least one element?
    except StopIteration:
        return vec

    if isinstance(first, (tuple, list)) and len(first) == 2:  # gensim sparse format
        print("INSIDE GENSIM SPARSE FORMAT HANDLING")
        if norm == 'l1':
            length = float(sum(abs(val) for _, val in vec))
        if norm == 'l2':
            length = 1.0 * math.sqrt(sum(val ** 2 for _, val in vec))
        assert length > 0.0, "sparse documents must not contain any explicit zero entries"
        return ret_normalized_vec(vec, length)
    else:
        raise ValueError("unknown input type")
```

When running tests, I want to check that the output from each of these methods is the same. Below is a snippet of example code:

```
vec = sparse.csr_matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).astype(np.float32)
output1 = manual_unitvec(vec)
output2 = unitvec(vec)
print(output1)
print(' ')
print(output2) 
print(np.array_equal(output1, output2))
print(type(output1) == type(output2))
```

So what I want to check is assertTrue(output1, output2). You can't do this because the truth value of arrays is ambiguous, so I use `assertTrue(np.array_equal(output1, output2))`.

Now the issue is that array_equal does not view output1 and output2 as being the same, even though I can see from printing them out that they are identical.

Running all of the code above gives the following output:

```
MacBook-Air:matutils.unitvec Olly$ python try.py
INSIDE SPARSE HANDLING
try.py:80: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.int64 == np.dtype(int).type`.
  if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int) == True:
  (0, 0)    0.059234887
  (0, 1)    0.118469775
  (0, 2)    0.17770466
  (1, 0)    0.23693955
  (1, 1)    0.29617444
  (1, 2)    0.35540932
  (2, 0)    0.4146442
  (2, 1)    0.4738791
  (2, 2)    0.53311396

  (0, 0)    0.059234887
  (0, 1)    0.118469775
  (0, 2)    0.17770466
  (1, 0)    0.23693955
  (1, 1)    0.29617444
  (1, 2)    0.35540932
  (2, 0)    0.4146442
  (2, 1)    0.4738791
  (2, 2)    0.53311396
/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:226: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using == is inefficient, try using != instead.
  " != instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
False
True
```

I thought that the issue might have come from the sparse array types, but as you can see, they are equal. You can also visually see that the elements are exactly the same.

So why is array_equal returning false? How can I change it?

Comment: There are some Warnings you may want to pay attention to. Also, try `np.allclose(output1, output2)` instead.

Comment: It seems that `np.array_equal` is not designed to work with sparse arrays. Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685839/9452806) accomplish what you are trying to do? `np.allclose(output1, output2)`

Comment: As a general rule `np.` functions do not work on sparse matrices.  You have to use sparse functions or methods (or numpy functions that delegate to sparse methods).  A sparse matrix is not a subclass of `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first function you do:

```
    vec = vec.tocsr()
    if sparse.issparse(vec):
```

I don't think the `issparse` test does anything for you.  If the input argument is a sparse matrix, it has a `tocsr` method, and the result is sparse matrix.  If `vec` is a `ndarray` is does not have a `tocsr` method, and the first line will throw an error.

In the rest of that function, a sparse matrix has a `multiply` method, and a `sum` method.  The result of `sum` is dense, so `np.sqrt` works fine on it.  Actually `np.sqrt(M)` also works on sparse matrix because `M.sqrt` exists.

In the second function you work with the `data` attribute, which is a 1d `ndarray`.

```
np.sum(np.abs(vec.data))
```

That's fine.  But notice that `M.__abs__` for a sparse matrix is

```
self._with_data(abs(self._deduped_data()))
```

In a slightly more round about way, funtions/methods like `abs`, `sqrt` work with the `.data` attribute as well.  Only they return a new sparse matrix.

As for the testing look at `np.array_equal`

```
return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())
```

If I try to use it on `output1` (I won't try your `gensim` solution

```
In [106]: np.array_equal(output1, output1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:226: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using == is inefficient, try using != instead.
  " != instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[106]: False
```

It doesn't like taking `==` on sparse matrices.  Usually these are large with many 0s.  That means the result will be `True` for all those, and hence no longer sparse.

Your `output1` is a sparse matrix, but, at least for these inputs, not sparse:

```
In [107]: output1.A
Out[107]: 
array([[0.05923489, 0.11846977, 0.17770466],
       [0.23693955, 0.29617444, 0.35540932],
       [0.4146442 , 0.4738791 , 0.53311396]], dtype=float32)
```

But even if you get around the sparsity bit, `np.array_equal(output1.A, output2.A)` could fail due to a comparison of floats

`allclose` on the dense versions is probably the simplest test:

```
In [113]: np.allclose(output1.A, output1.A)
Out[113]: True
```

You could also compare the `data` (assuming the sparsity is the same):

```
In [114]: np.allclose(output1.data, output1.data)
Out[114]: True
```

A fuller sparse test would need to check `shape`, `nnz`, and `indices` attributes.

Actually I'm not sure where `np.array_equal` is failing.  Notice that it starts with `a1=asarray(a1)`, which produces a 0d object dtype array.  This is one of those `numpy` functions that insists on treating its inputs as arrays.  It is not sparse aware.