# Scipy: Sparse indicator matrix from array(s)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, indicator

What is the most efficient way to compute a sparse boolean matrix `I` from one or two arrays `a,b`, with `I[i,j]==True` where `a[i]==b[j]`? The following is fast but memory-inefficient:

```
I = a[:,None]==b
```

The following is slow and still memory-inefficient during creation:

```
I = csr((a[:,None]==b),shape=(len(a),len(b)))
```

The following gives at least the rows,cols for better `csr_matrix` initialization, but it still creates the full dense matrix and is equally slow:

```
z = np.argwhere((a[:,None]==b))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I could do the whole tour with argsorting a, detect the indeces where sorted array changes, calculate the combinations of each size of partition determined this way, unsort again... But I hope there is a simple numpy or scipy function at hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to first identify all different elements that `a` and `b` have in common using `set`s. This should work well if there are not very many different possibilities for the values in `a` and `b`. One then would only have to loop over the different values (below in variable `values`) and use `np.argwhere` to identify the indices in `a` and `b` where these values occur. The 2D indices of the sparse matrix can then be constructed using `np.repeat` and `np.tile`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(400,))
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(300,))

## matrix generation after OP
I1 = sparse.csr_matrix((a[:,None]==b),shape=(len(a),len(b)))

##identifying all values that occur both in a and b:
values = set(np.unique(a)) & set(np.unique(b))

##here we collect the indices in a and b where the respective values are the same:
rows, cols = [], []

##looping over the common values, finding their indices in a and b, and
##generating the 2D indices of the sparse matrix with np.repeat and np.tile
for value in values:
    x = np.argwhere(a==value).ravel()
    y = np.argwhere(b==value).ravel()    
    rows.append(np.repeat(x, len(x)))
    cols.append(np.tile(y, len(y)))

##concatenating the indices for different values and generating a 1D vector
##of True values for final matrix generation
rows = np.hstack(rows)
cols = np.hstack(cols)
data = np.ones(len(rows),dtype=bool)

##generating sparse matrix
I3 = sparse.csr_matrix( (data,(rows,cols)), shape=(len(a),len(b)) )

##checking that the matrix was generated correctly:
print((I1 != I3).nnz==0)
```

The syntax for generating the csr matrix is taken from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix). The test for sparse matrix equality is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685839/2454357).

**Old Answer**:

I don't know about performance, but at least you can avoid constructing the full dense matrix by using a simple generator expression. Here some code that uses two 1d arras of random integers to first generate the sparse matrix the way that the OP posted and then uses a generator expression to test all elements for equality:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(400,))
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(300,))

## matrix generation after OP
I1 = sparse.csr_matrix((a[:,None]==b),shape=(len(a),len(b)))

## matrix generation using generator
data, rows, cols = zip(
    *((True, i, j) for i,A in enumerate(a) for j,B in enumerate(b) if A==B)
)
I2 = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(len(a), len(b)))

##testing that matrices are equal
## from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685839/2454357
print((I1 != I2).nnz==0)  ## --> True
```

I think there is no way around the double loop and ideally this would be pushed into `numpy`, but at least with the generator the loops are somewhat optimised ...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too slow :(

Comment: @RadioControlled how big are your matrices?

Comment: I tried 15000 by 15000 with 10 different values, but of course it depends mostly on the sparsity of the equality matrix, which depends on the distribution of different values.

Comment: @RadioControlled Sure, but my suggestion is slow because you have to iterate over all i and all j of the 1d arrays. Maybe with the sorting you suggested one could indeed speed up things, but I don't think that there is anything inbuilt...

Comment: @RadioControlled I had another idea -- please have a look at the edit in my answer.

Comment: That seems to be a good solution! I think the first suggestion can be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use  [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with small tolerance:

```
np.isclose(a,b)
```

Or [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html#pandas.DataFrame.eq):

```
a.eq(b)
```

Note this returns an array of `True` `False`.

Comment: Seems to me that `np.isclose(a[:,None],b)` returns a dense array, too. Same for pandas, plus more dependencies required...